# UIView is not receiving the touch event

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad

I'm beginner in Ipad development, so I'm trying to do an application that will have some of the twitter application features.

The issue is that I have a UIViewController which has the content. When you click on a image it should show a view that has a video in it, all above each others (as in twitter APP), the issue is that the view is appearing and it shows the subviews in it, but it dose not receive any touch event and doesn't get the background color.

So can you help me?

thanks :P

Comment: I think we cannot help without any code sample

Comment: actually, i don't know what is the issue that is why i don't know what part of the code you want, i can post the hole project if you want ,,, i can upload it to a sever and post the link for you,

Answer (score 3):

Make sure that the userInteraction is enabled for the image view. You can  do it from the Interface builder, or alternatively, do -
`myImageView.userInteractionEnabled = YES`
You can then add gesture recognizer to that imageView- in your case a tap gesture recognizer. That should work. To add a gesture recognizer:

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGestureRec = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]  initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleTap:)];
[myImageView addGestureRecognizer:tapGestureRec];
```

Then handle the tap in the handleTap: method.

Comment: ,, that what i did ,, but still the same

Comment: You should conform to UIGestureRecognizerDelegate protocol, and assign the delegate to your view controller object. You can refer to this link: http://www.ioslearner.com/implementing-gesture-recognizers-iphoneipad/. It shows how to implement gesture recognizers. This is quite similar to your requirement.